# checkbox used in li tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want to click on a list item and have all the checkboxes within that list item to be checked, and unchecked if I click on another list item - acting as a radio system. How can I do this? Here's my current code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not just use `radio` inputs...? Then you get this behaviour by default. Also you appear to have made no attempt to solve this yourself, so it's just a 'write my code for me' request

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think OP wants all checkboxes in an li to be selected on clicking it while unselecting all other checkboxes from other li elements.. If radio buttons are used only one can be active at a time

Comment: So, you want to ensure that within an `li` only one checkbox is checked at any time? Please re-phrase your first paragraph if this is your requirement.

Comment: i want check all checkbox within li when click on li , all checkbox is check but i click other li then prevision li checkbox is unchecked and this is checked all checkbox.

Comment: chirag ravindra you right i want all check box is check after clicking on li i not use radio becuase my name key is all different.

Comment: I think what OP wants to achieve is to have the checkboxes that are "grouped" within the li elements to be activated at once the li element - or any checkbox in it - is clicked/activated. "Activating" another group in this manner would disable all checkboxes in other groups.
Is my interpretation of the question correct, @traini-qula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that you listen for clicks on the li elements and check every checkbox in it on click and uncheck all checkboxes which are not in the li element. Sample code below

```js
$(function() {
  var $li = $('li.checkall');
  var $checkboxes = $li.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  $('li.checkall').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this) return;
    var $this = $(this);
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    $this.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  })
})
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('li.checkall').on('click', function() {
        $('.check_one').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).find('.check_one').each(function() {
              $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });

    });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 $("li").click(function(e){ 
  if (e.target !== this) return;
  $("li input").prop('checked', false);
  $(this).find("input").prop('checked', true);
 })
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("li").click(function() {
    $("li").each(function(index, item) {
      $(item).css({
        backgroundColor: "gray"
      });
    });

    
    $(this).css({
      backgroundColor: "red"
    });

    $(".check_one").each(function(index, item) {
      $(item).prop('checked', false);
    })

    $(this).find(".check_one").each(function(index, item) {
      $(item).prop('checked', true);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
    <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
  </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

Added backgroundColor: "red" on active LI

Comment: thanks friends its working....but if i also want to change background color.for example i click li and then red color is add on li same as checbox.

Comment: after i click other li then prevsion li red is remove and checked li is cover with red

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:)

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(event){
        $('input').prop('checked', false);
        $(event.target).parent().children().prop('checked', true);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Exactly you case:

```
<ul>
        <li class="btn checkall">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
        </li>
        <li class="btn checkall">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
        </li>
        <li class="btn checkall">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
        </li>
      <li class="btn checkall">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
            <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript :

```
 $('.checkall').click(function() {
    $('.checkall').find('.check_one').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).find('.check_one').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($){

 
 $(document).on('click','li',function(){
  //console.log($(this).find('.check_one'));
  $('.check_one').prop('checked',false)
  $(this).children('.check_one').prop('checked',true);
 });

});
```

```css
.btn{
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border : 1px solid black;
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
 <li class="btn checkall">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
 </li>
 <li class="btn checkall">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
 </li>
 <li class="btn checkall">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
 </li>
  <li class="btn checkall">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key1]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key2]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key3]" class="check_one">
  <input type="checkbox" name="offer[key4]" class="check_one">
 </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```